# CartThrob Permissions FieldType added to product channel now I get error:

Tags: cartthrob, error, fieldtype, permissions

After I add the CartThrob Permissions field to my product channel, I am no longer able to edit my channel.  If I select channel > edit and then click a product I desire to edit, I get the following:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to locate the model you have specified: cartthrob_field_model

- Expression Engine version 2.7.3
- CartThrob version 2.4

What can I do, or what additional information would be helpful to debug this?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to replicate the error you're reporting. A new Cartthrob Permissions Admin module (version 2.5) was released today. I would recommend installing that update and if you continue to have this problem book a support appointment here: http://support.mightybigrobot.com

Comment: I updated to CartThrob version 2.5 and I still have the  error as described above in my original question.  I will be opening a support appointment as you mentioned above.

Comment: I must not have been installing version 2.5 correctly, but with help from CartThrob, reinstalling version 2.5 fixed the problem.